# Text Classification into Categories - is there any available models which suitable for this in BigQuery ML or Python (Google Colab)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-bigquery, classification, google-colaboratory

I'm having a database about SKUs in retails which looks like below:

| SKU | Category | Sub-Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| brand A UHT milk | Dairy | Fresh Milk |
| brand B Yogurt | Dairy | Yogurt |
| Fresh Milk from brand B | Dairy | Fresh Milk |
| Super Instant Noodle from brand C | Noodle | Instant Noodle |
| Bacon with love from brand D | Ready-to-cook | Bacon |
| Best Toilet Paper from brand E | Household | Toilet Paper |

At the moment it has more than 100k records, and only 60% of them has category and sub-category data.

As the retailer always tries to look for products from new brand to join in our business with the aim of creating a healthy competitive environment, we usually get around 100 new SKUs per day. Combining with the remaining 40% missing data, we have tons of work to do manually.

I've read about classification model on BQML, but not sure it was the right method.

So here I am, finding a model (or article, paper, Python library, etc. sorry I'm kinda new in this field so I may not have the right keywords to google it) to learn the pattern from fulfilled data then they can detect new SKU's category and sub-category base on SKU name. So with that the staffs can reduce lots of workload, and spend more time on doing something else less boring.

I'm using BigQuery and Colab as my main tools for data manipulating, so it would be great if I can get suggested models from you guys in those IDE. Or from anywhere else it still be fine, I will read all.

Thank you so much for reading :D

Comment: Hi @dogolearnpython, Does this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/introduction) help you?

Comment: Did the above comment help in resolving the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use any classification models from BQML (see here for a full list: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-e2e-journey#model_creation_phase)

However, it looks like you have 2 labels: category and sub-category. BQML doesn't support multi-label models. Therefore, I think you may train two classification models, one using category as the label, the other using sub-category as the label.